# WPF Mahapps - How to hide a tab within Hamburger Menu collection?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro, hamburger-menu

Note: I'm using *MVVM Light Toolkit* and *MahApps.Metro*

So I have a `HamburgerMenu` control within my application, it contains a `HamburgerMenuImageItem`s within `HamburgerMenuItemCollection`.
What I'd like to do is to hide one item and show another depending on what user is logged in. I have all the information, I know who the user is and whether he/she's allowed to see the tab, but I have no idea how to hide the tab.

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu>
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
                <controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem Label="Global">
                    <controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Thumbnail>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="../../Resources/Icons/test.png" />
                    </controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Thumbnail>
                    <controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Tag>
                        <views:GlobalView />
                    </controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Tag>
                </controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem>

                <controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem Label="Local">
                    <controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Thumbnail>
                        <BitmapImage UriSource="../../Resources/Icons/test.png" />
                    </controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Thumbnail>
                    <controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Tag>
                        <views:LocalView />
                    </controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem.Tag>
                </controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem>
        </controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
</controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

There's more code within that I think it's not relevant (DataTemplates for showing content).

I'm not sure if it's possible, but let's say that if `User` is logged in which is not allowed to see Local tab, local tab would be hidden.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just give the `HamburgerMenuImageItem` an `x:Name` in your XAML markup and remove it programmatically in the code-behind of your view:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="menu">
    <controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
        <controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
            ...
            <controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem Label="Local" x:Name="local">
                ...
            </controls:HamburgerMenuImageItem>
        </controls:HamburgerMenuItemCollection>
    </controls:HamburgerMenu.ItemsSource>
</controls:HamburgerMenu>
```

---

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if(/* user is logged in...*/)
        {
            HamburgerMenuItemCollection itemCollection = menu.ItemsSource as HamburgerMenuItemCollection;
            itemCollection.Remove(local);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As usual, mm8 to rescue. :)
Also, do you think there's a way to do this in MVVM fashion? After all , everything (well, 95% of things) I've done has been done in ViewModel.

Comment: Well, since you are creating the HamburgerMenuImageItem in the view, you might as well remove it from the view as well. The MVVM way would otherwise be to bind to a collection of (data) items that you define in the view model and then define the template for each of the data types in the view.

Comment: I get it :)
I'll try doing it MVVM later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. I've attached a Loaded EventHandler to the HamburgerMenu:

```
<controls:HamburgerMenu [...] Loaded="HamburgerMenuLoaded" />
```

and in the code behind:

```
private void HamburgerMenuLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is HamburgerMenu hamburgerMenu)
    {
        if (hamburgerMenu.Template.FindName("ButtonsListView", hamburgerMenu) is ListBox listBox)
        {
            var style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem))
                        {
                            BasedOn = listBox.ItemContainerStyle
                        };

            style.Triggers.Add(new DataTrigger
                               {
                                   Binding = new Binding(nameof(ITabViewModel.ShowTab)),
                                   Value = false,
                                   Setters =
                                   {
                                       new Setter(VisibilityProperty, Visibility.Collapsed)
                                   }
                               });

            listBox.ItemContainerStyle = style;
        }
    }
}
```

The property in my ViewModel is a bool called `ShowTab`, which I'm using for the binding.